# Open GooglePlay Rating Section directly?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I want to have a "Rate the app" button in my Android app which directly links to the rating section from my app's google play page.

I know how to open the google play page of my app with a button click.

**Is there a way to open the section of the google play app page where the user can rate the app directly?**

Answer (score 5):

According to [**official documentation**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)... you can't.

There is only 3 types of Intent for the Google Play Store:

1-

Type: Show the product details page for a specific app

Web URL: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name

Intent URI: market://details?id=package_name

2-

Type: Show apps by a specific publisher

Web URL: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:publisher_name

Intent URI: market://search?q=pub:publisher_name

3-

Type: Search for apps using a general string query.

Web URL: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=query

Intent URI: market://search?q=query

EDIT: There is also a 4th type: **Linking to a Collection** to open the Top Paid, Top Free, Editor's Choice, etc apps. (Follow the official documentation)

The way you make the Intent is like always:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```